# VBA-IE10 Storing table Object?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I have figured out how to rotate through a web based table to find specific information. At the end of the table are some buttons i will want to interact with later the `<td>` inner text is `"Amend"`. this however is in the source code as `<td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Amend</a></td>`

so here is my looping code

```
   Set tbl = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)
    Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

     For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
        Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")
        'if no <td> then look for <th>
        If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("th")

        For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
            If tds(c).innerText Like "471*" Then

                Storage(d, 0) = tds(c).innerText
                Storage(d, 1) = tds(c + 2).innerText
                Storage(d, 2) = tds(c + 4).innerText
                If tds(c + 6).innerText = "Amend" Then
                    Set Amen_BTN(d, 0) = tds(c + 6).****BUT WHAT GOES HERE!?*****
                    End If

                d = d + 1
            Debug.Print tds(c).innerText
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
```

So what goes in the ***** to allow me store the button to use later on   `Amen_BTN(0, 0).Click` I hope this is an understandable question,

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: OK so i have realized i need to be referencing a Link <a> I don't know if i need to reference the Href for storing the item or what? I cant even manage to click the Link. It just seems to never reference the link in any IF statements I have found for searching for a link. The problem i am having (i think) is that i am in the table and this is confusing me :(

Comment: `<div id="divResults" style="float: left">
  
    <table id="tblResults" >
        
   
        <thead><tr><th></th><th>Booking Ref</th><th>Pickup Location</th><th>Passenger Name</th><th>Destination Location</th><th>Date Time</th><th>Status</th><th colspan="3">Options</th></tr></thead>
    
`This is the table start for refence if it helps anyone!

Comment: Your question is confusing to me as well, so we are both confused :). You want to grab the `anchor` elements from the table and save them into some sort of `collection` to call `click` on them later? Do I understand it correctly? Is the `URL` public? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: @ Dee, Thanks for the reply, The site sadly is not public, What I am doing is searching for a specific Job number that relates to several Taxi Bookings on the site. this then populates a table The first in the column of each row is the job number. at the other end of the table is 3 buttons (for active jobs) these are stored in 3 more rows at the end of each row. I want to basically store the Booking number and the Hyperlink/Button relating to each booking. in the hope to later Mass ammend each booking by cycling through the Links and clicking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the html-snippet of the page and reading your comments I finally understand what are you trying to achieve. But this is IMO not possible :(.

The last cell has the following content:

```
<td>
    <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" 
        id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0" 
        class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        Amend
    </a>
</td>
```

So it contains an `anchor` element with java-script confirm call. When the user confirms the *amend* then the `_doPostBack` function will be called receiving the name of the control which caused the [post-back](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=895&pId=-1) which then performs the submit of the `form`. So the whole page is send to the server in a *POST* request and on the server *it* does something with the data and returns a resulting page back. The *it* denotes some server logic which expects some parameters and returns results. So when the grid `tblResults` doesn't offer bulk processing of more then one item at a time, then it is probably not possible or safe to process more then one at a time. So here you can just click one *amend* and let the server to process the request and then get the new data back from the server and process next one etc. Is it understandable? HTH

---

> *EDIT*:
>
> - How to click the `anchor` element with VBA:
>
> Here in this example `querySelector` method is used. We specify the
>   selector to the specific `anchor` element e.g. like this:
>
> ```
> div[id='divResults'] table[id='tblResults'] tbody td 
> a[id='MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0']
> ```

The complete code then could look like this, HTH.

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Sub ClickOnAmendBooking()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String

    url = "file:///c:/Temp/StackOverflow/html/"
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate url & "Chris_livermore.html"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    Set doc = ie.document

    Dim btnAmendBooking As HTMLAnchorElement
    Set btnAmendBooking = doc.querySelector("div[id='divResults'] table[id='tblResults'] tbody td a[id='MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0']")

    If Not btnAmendBooking Is Nothing Then
        btnAmendBooking.Click
    Else
        MsgBox "btnAmendBooking was not found on webpage"
    End If

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

> Result:
>   [image]

Comment: Hi Dee, Appologies for the very very late reply I have been away from work on holiday! Yes I undertsna dhwta you are saying, as i was working my through i was starting to think this would not be a simple fix! I Shall get working on a way of rotating round the required "Clicks" to automate this horrible process! thanks for your help and patients!

Comment: Dee, IM struggling again. How would I go about automatically clicking this object? as the only way i have seen to work is to store the object of a button from a page... sorry to be a pain and keep pestering you!

Comment: @Chris_livermore see edited answer with example how to click the anchor element. When the anchor element is clicked then the alert is displayed. HTH

Comment: Dee you truly are amazing! that is a beautiful example! Thank you very much!

Comment: Dee, Is there a Simple way of emulating a Enter Click within IE to then bypass the popup? I am currently working with this example and it seems rather long winded for what i need to actually do...  http://www.siddharthrout.com/2013/04/24/unprotecting-vba-project-password-using-a-password-that-you-know/

Comment: @Chris_livermore this seems to me as a candidate for new question, but have a look e.g. [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d60db722-9f0c-4558-8654-2e3206d55834/how-to-click-on-pop-up-box-in-internet-explorer-using-vba?forum=isvvba).

Answer (score 1):

For those who want the source,

```html
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Pager$btnNext" value="Next" id="MainContent_Pager_btnNext" Page="2" style="height:19px;width:40px;" />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Pager$btnLast" value="Last" id="MainContent_Pager_btnLast" Page="2" style="height:19px;width:61px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Total pages:2
</div>

<div id="divResults" style="float: left">
  
    <table id="tblResults" >
        
   
        <thead><tr><th></th><th>Booking Ref</th><th>Pickup Location</th><th>Passenger Name</th><th>Destination Location</th><th>Date Time</th><th>Status</th><th colspan="3">Options</th></tr></thead>
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4734464);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4734464</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> STP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">10/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
             Amend</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_0" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_0" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                Cancel</a></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4734463);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4734463</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">09/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_1" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl02$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
             Amend</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_1" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl02$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_1" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl02$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                Cancel</a></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4734462);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4734462</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">08/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_2" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl03$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
             Amend</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_2" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl03$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_2" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl03$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                Cancel</a></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4734461);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4734461</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">07/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_3" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl04$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
             Amend</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_3" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl04$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_3" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl04$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                Cancel</a></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4734460);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4734460</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">06/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_4" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl05$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
             Amend</a></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_4" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl05$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_4" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl05$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
                Cancel</a></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713706);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713706</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">03/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_5" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl06$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713705);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713705</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">02/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_6" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl07$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713704);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713704</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">01/03/2017 20:04</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_7" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl08$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4719527);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4719527</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> CLIFTONVILLE WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE ROAD, ST LEONARDS ON SEA, EAST SUSSEX, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> Andrew Hansen</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, SEVENOAKS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">28/02/2017 21:10</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusUnknown">Amended</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_8" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl09$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713703);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713703</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> Andrew Hanson</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">28/02/2017 20:00</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusCancelled">Cancelled</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_9" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl10$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
         
         
      
         <tr>
             <td rowspan="3">
                 <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713702);">View</button>
             </td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713702</div></td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> Paul Kennard</div></td>
            <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
            <td rowspan="3">27/02/2017 20:00</td>            
            <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusUnknown">Amended</span></td>    
           
            <td></td>
         </tr>
            <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_10" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl11$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
            <tr><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: This should give you some idea of what i am wanting to store and use later.